# Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token (at react.js?v=ce04ce93:1:1)

Tags: reactjs, environment-variables

I have this error on my react app anytime I start the server.
i do not know what is wrong here, can some help me out

i was expecting my react app to render properly

Below is the error i usually encounter when i start the development

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token (at react.js?v=ce04ce93:1:1)
```

Comment: did you have the same issue when you start with a new react app ?

Comment: Can you share your code

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.